# Powershell Unable to find type [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat]

Tags: powershell

I'm using this script to convert DOC to HTML

```
param([string]$docpath,[string]$htmlpath = $docpath)

$srcfiles = Get-ChildItem $docPath -filter "*.doc"
$saveFormat = [Enum]::Parse([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat], "wdFormatFilteredHTML");
$word = new-object -comobject word.application
$word.Visible = $False

function saveas-filteredhtml
{
    $opendoc = $word.documents.open($doc.FullName);
    $opendoc.saveas([ref]"$htmlpath\$doc.fullname.html", [ref]$saveFormat);
    $opendoc.close();
}

ForEach ($doc in $srcfiles)
{
    Write-Host "Processing :" $doc.FullName
    saveas-filteredhtml
    $doc = $null
}

$word.quit();
```

Unfortunately when I run it for the first time in the ISE console I get this error

```
Unable to find type [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat].
In F:\PS\NEW\main.ps1:108 car:29
+ ...  = [Enum]::Parse([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat], "wdFor ...
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Offic...rd.WdSaveFormat:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

While if I run it from the same console again the second time it works fine.

How can I solve the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Loading the Word assemblies is actually a two-step process in [PowerShell Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/differences-from-windows-powershell?view=powershell-7.3): First, add the base assemblies into the pwsh environment; then, add the target interop assembly.

Thanks to [@Patrick Meinecke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1930135/patrick-meinecke) for clarifying this [on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11281#issuecomment-562891633).

```pwsh
# First load MS Office base assemblies into the environment
Add-Type -Path $env:WINDIR\assembly\GAC_MSIL\office\*\office.dll -PassThru  # Use -PassThru to verify it worked (otherwise, fails silently)
# Then, add the target MS Word assembly
Get-ChildItem -Path $env:windir\assembly -Recurse -Filter Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word* -File | ForEach-Object {
    Add-Type -LiteralPath ($_.FullName) -PassThru # Use -PassThru to verify it worked (otherwise, fails silently)
}
```

Then, you can automate the Word application for your own needs. For example, convert all `txt` files into `docx`:

```pwsh
$wordApp = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
if($null -eq $wordApp){
    Write-Host "Failed to create Word.Application object"
    exit
}
foreach ($txt in Get-ChildItem -Path . -Filter *.txt)
{
    try
    {
        $wordDoc = $wordApp.Documents.Add()
        $wordDocWindow = $wordDoc.ActiveWindow
        $wordDocWindow.Selection.InsertFile(('"' + ($txt | Get-ShortPath | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ShortPath ) + '"'))
        $wordDoc.SaveAs([ref]$(Join-Path $txt.Directory.FullName -ChildPath $txt.BaseName))
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
$wordApp.Quit()
[void][System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($wordApp)
[GC]::Collect()
[GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

I tested this on my machine and it was able to convert all `txt` into `docx`.

These are syntheses of techniques provided within [Justin Loring's ConvertTo-OSCWord](https://gist.github.com/justinloring/4baebea4aec613e30ed9870e540e28b7) and [Steve Knutson's blog post *converting word document format with powershell*](https://steveknutson.blog/2021/06/09/converting-word-document-format-with-powershell/); although both of those are incomplete and only used as guides.

Answer (score 0):

In this forum they solve the problem:https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/6f7eee4b-1f42-499e-ae59-1aceb26100de/view/Discussions

you add this lines at the beginning of your code:

```html
$wdTypes = Add-Type -AssemblyName 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word' -Passthru
$wdSaveFormat = $wdTypes | Where {$_.Name -eq "wdSaveFormat"}
```